# How do I Know the CheckBox is selected?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have generated  checkboxesat runtime inside listbox, the problem is how can i know what are the selected checkboxes?

I tried The following code in C#:

```
CheckBox box;
if ( box.Checked )
if ( box.IsChecked )
```

This is the following code:

```
public partial class Choose_Users
{
    Service1Client C = new Service1Client();
    Array a;
    user_detail d;
    String F_Name, L_Name;
    CheckBox user = new CheckBox();

    public Choose_Users()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        a = C.GetData();            

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            d = (user_detail)a.GetValue(i);                
            user.Name = d.First_name;
            user.Content= d.First_name;
            listBox1.Items.Add(user);                
        }
    }
    private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<user_detail> list = new List<user_detail>();
            foreach(CheckBox box in this.listBox1.Items)
            {
                if (box.Checked  // here my problem is
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

they didn't work. Any help ?

Comment: @Sofia, you have posted a question that gives very little context as to what language, environment, etc you are using to check this. Please edit your question with relevant details and update the tags to reflect what you are trying to get an answer on.

Comment: "It doesn't work" an no response to questions. Voting to close.

Comment: box.Checked definitely won't do anything as it's the event.  box.IsChecked will return whether the box is checked or not.

Comment: Mr.coldandtired, I tried it in the condition (if (box.IsChecked)) gives me error that it cant convarte from 'bool?' to 'bool'.

Comment: Are you sure you have `listbox` not `checkedListbox`? As far as I know there is not checkbox items in standard listbox

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of programming language, you need to keep a reference to the checkboxes you dynamically create.

You can do this by **creating** your checkbox outside of any local methods and/or events:

```
CheckBox box;
```

and then **assign** inside of local method or events:

```
box = new CheckBox();
```

Then you can access *box* anywhere else in your code and box.IsChecked will work as you are wanting.

Comment: It didn't work. I've edit my question and post the code. would you plz check it.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the for loop in Choose_Users with the following one. The following code creates a new checkbox object everytime .

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
   CheckBox user = new CheckBox();
   d = (user_detail)a.GetValue(i);
   user.Name = d.First_name;
   user.Content= d.First_name;
   listBox1.Items.Add(user);                
}
```

Regarding the checkstate , box.Checked is perfect.

Let me know if this helped you.

Comment: Thank you. I replaced it. but still the same problem, specially I need to know the checked boxes in other loops like.

Comment: foreach (CheckBox box in (c_u.listBox1.Items))
            {
               if (box.IsChecked == true) //here the problem
    {

Comment: Sofia , what does a contain. In your code, A refers to an unitialized array. Maybe you can debug the code using breakpoints and see the value of each user.

Answer (score 0):

we create string selectedItem and assign to it the selected item of check boxList as follow:

```
string selectedItem = Box.SelectedItem.Text;
```